# How to configure fields and views in Drupal 7?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

Drupal 7.x:
how to configure fields and views (and other modules if required) to get javascript image viewer like samples below?

http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/images/B000TER4HO/

http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/images/B00126INHI/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the images are field values of a node (recommended): http://drupal.org/project/field_slideshow

   Create an image field with Unlimited values and set up the field's display on `admin/structure/types/manage/NODE_TYPE/display`. (The Slideshow option has some options.)

   [image]
2. If the images are separate nodes connected to the product node someshow: http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow

   You'll need to create a view that loads the image nodes for this. Probably with a relationship to the current node.

Comment: How to configure the Field Slideshow to switch between thumbnails and large images, like the above amazon examples?

Comment: I improved the answer. You don't need a View with Field Slideshow. It's a field display option/widget.

Comment: I did it already, installed Field Slideshow, followed tutorial, configured it the way you posted. But there is no thumbnails, it have big image and Prev, Next controls under the image, and it look completely different.

Comment: Don't configure it like the screenshot =) That was just a screenshot to show the available settings. The "Pager" setting has an image option. If you choose that, you get more settings, i.e. "Pager image style" where you can set the thumbnail image style.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. The only issue is that thumbnails have different size(height). Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: You can create an image style to make all thumbnails the same size on `admin/config/media/image-styles`. You'll want the "Scale and crop" effect.